# Woocommerce product add to cart custom data img

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shopping-cart, jcanvas

Hi everyone I have a question about woocommerce and custom metadata.

In my simple product page I had a 2D canvas made with jcanvas. All work well I can adjust height and width based on the product data and modify them.

Then before adding to cart I export an image base64 from my canvas and add it to the cart item because it's a thechnical data. 
When I go to cart page. I have an error 414. Request uri too long. 
So I try to generate blob image which work on single product page but not on cart item.

Also try to did that with a base64 image. It works but in my cart item img src data: is automatically removed and don't know why ...

Strangely it remove in my img src the blob: part ...

So my question is how I can send my png canvas image to a cart item and attach to it to display in a thumbnail ?

Thanks

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem.

It due to wp_kses_post that auto remove my data:  for security reason. 
So I modify cart-item-data template and avoir this function. 
This work like this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to explain how you were able to do this? I have the exact same issue. Thanks in advance.